# Crash when startup build iOS flutter

Tags: crash, flutter

I have the exact issue. My app is installing fine on several iphones but the same crashes at startup. Running the app manually from Xcode produces this on the console :

> 2018-10-24 16:30:34.984717+0700 Runner[9026:1109274]
>   [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm.cc(263)] VM snapshot must be valid.
>
> 2018-10-24 16:30:34.984844+0700 Runner[9026:1109274]
>   [VERBOSE-3:shell.cc(216)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize
>   the VM.

Anyone have idea to fix it ?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19858

Comment: @anmol.majhail I tried some solution in that topic, but my app still crash when startup

Comment: I fixed my bug. I created new project and then copy Code, Resources, Libs from old project to new project.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, solved by

1. In xcode, "Product"->"Clean Build Folder"
2. flutter clean
3. flutter run --release